# How to create IIS website alias on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008-r2

I created a new Training website on my Windows Server 2008 R2 sp1 machine on port 8020. The URL is `http://WACME321:8020`. We would like to have a `http://APP-train` URL instead. How can I change the website alias to `http://APP-train`? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in two steps.

The first is you'll need to change the listen port to 80 (unless you want to add the 8020 to the end of the URL).

The second step is you'll need to set up the Host Headers in IIS for that website to listen to `http://APP-train`

While a little dated, this guide can help you become more familiar with Host Headers - this will make website administration much easier for you in IIS. http://www.it-notebook.org/iis/article/understanding_host_headers.htm